# Product of subgroups of a group $G$ is a subgroup then of them is a normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I'm studying some group theory again and I came across with the following proposition:

Let $G$ be a group. If $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$ and $H$ is normal in $G$ then their product $HK := \{hk|h\in H, k\in K\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I was wondering if we can have some kind of converse, like: Let $G$ be a group. If $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$ and their product $HK := \{hk|h\in H, k\in K\}$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $H$ or $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

I have no ideia if this is true. I didn't even managed to start a draft of a proof. I also couldn't give some counter examples, since my repertory with group theory is very basic.

I will appreciate a lot if someome could give me a hint or some reference. Thanks.

Comment: Well, an obvious counterexample would be to take $H=K$.

Comment: Omg, that was really obvious hahaha. Maybe if I improve my question and ask them to be different, I would have a decent question. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to practice a bit, try to prove that $HK$ is a subgroup if and only if $HK=KH$. This is indeed an equivalent condition.

Comment: Just asking for the subgroups to be different won't get you round a slight variant of lulu's observation. In a product group $G = G' \times G''$, you could take $H = H' \times 1$ and $K = H' \times G''$.

Comment: Thanks for the exercise, @Mark, I was able to do it! :)

Comment: Are you supposing that $H'$ isn't a normal subgroup in $G'$, @RobArthan? I'm sorry if it is a dumb question, I haven't seen product group yet, but I'm really near to study that subject in my classes.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: Thanks, @RobArthan!